# Сколько существует триад точек, заданных координатами, которые образуют прямоугольный треугольник?

Tags: c#, математика, координаты

```
string[] line = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt", Encoding.Default);

int Points = Convert.ToInt32(line[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < Points; i++)
{

}

StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("output.txt", true, Encoding.Default);
write.WriteLine();

write.Close();
```

Сначала появилась мысль счиать все в двумерный массив, но как проверять я не представляю
Подскажите, как реализовать эту самую проверку, пример входных и выходных данных:

```
input
5
0 3
0 0
1 0
4 0
4 1
```

```
output
5
```

Comment: Триад точек образующих прямоугольный треугольник существует бесконечное количество.

Comment: @Эникейщик они на входе же заданы, точки. Точки сами искать не надо.

Comment: ну и ищете все которые, которые "пифагоровы штаны" :)

Comment: это будет очень большую нагрузку давать и код будет нагроможденный, пока циклами переберем все длины и их между собой сравниваем

Comment: мне кажется надо от значений точек отталкиваться. Берете 2 точки - если они на одной вертикальной или одной горизонтальной линии находятся, но не совпадают - то третья точка может быть любой, если не находтся на той же линии, что и первые две. Если же две точки на разных горизонталях/вертикалях, то они уже образуют прямоугольник, останется только остальные 2 угла прямоугольника найти и проверить их сущестование в исходном наборе.

Answer (score 1):

За квадратичное время - считаете угловые коэффициенты для каждой пары точек

```
m = abs((y2-y1) / (x2-x1))
```

и складываете их в мап, содержащий пары коэффициент-счётчик. Отдельно держите счётчики для коэффициента 0 и бесконечного (для вертикальных линий).

При вычислении очередного коэффициента проверяете, есть ли в map обратный ему 1/m и учитываете соответствующий счётчик в результате.
Учтите точность сравнения.